# Mongoose - model methods not found in middleware

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, model

It's possible that i'm just burned out, but I have the following models:

user

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validate = require('mongoose-validator');
const Post = require('./post');

let UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    lastName: { type: String, required: true },
    email: {
        type: String, required: true, lowercase: true, trim: true, unique: true, index: true,
        validate: [validate({ validator: 'isEmail', message: 'Invalid Email!' })]
    },
    posts: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

posts

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./user');

let PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    body: { type: String, require: true }
})

PostSchema.post('save', async function (next) {
    await User.update({ _id: this.user }, { $push: { posts: this._id } })
    return next();
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

When trying to add a new post, the post save hook runs, but I get the error User.update is not a function (same goes for findOneAndUpdate, findOne, etc).

I can call user.update from the rest of the app without issues, so not sure whats happening here. Both models are in the same directory.

Comment: Small observation but it really should not be necessary to maintain the array anyway. You already have the user id value on the post and could simply use a "virtual" ( or just don't bother and use `$lookup` always ) on the `User` instead of keeping an array. Also noting that 9/10 times you probably should be embedding anyway. There would not even be a single answer on stackoverflow which would cause embedded detail in MongoDB to actually breach the 16MB BSON limit. Just for curiosity here though, what happens if you remove the async/await and even the next to make this a serial action?

Comment: Same result using callbacks instead of Async, ur ideas are probably better but now this is bothering me and I need to find out the reason for it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you missed is that `post` middleware has the first argument as the "document" and not the `next` handler:

#### user.js

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');


const userSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  posts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }]
});
```

#### post.js

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = require('./user');

const postSchema = new Schema({
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  title: String,
  body: String
});

// note that first argument is the "document" as in "post" once it was created
postSchema.post('save', async function(doc, next) {
  await User.update({ _id: doc.user._id },{ $push: { posts: doc._id } });
  next();
});
```

#### index.js

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = require('./user');
const Post = require('./post');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/posttest';

mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri);

    await Promise.all(Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.remove()));

    let user = await User.create({ firstName: 'Ted', lastName: 'Logan' });

    let post = new Post({ user: user._id, title: 'Hi', body: 'Whoa!' });
    post = await post.save();

    mongoose.disconnect();

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    process.exit()
  }

})()
```

Returns:

```
Mongoose: users.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: posts.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: users.insertOne({ posts: [], _id: ObjectId("5b0217001b5a55208150cc9b"), firstName: 'Ted', lastName: 'Logan', __v: 0 })
Mongoose: posts.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("5b0217001b5a55208150cc9c"), user: ObjectId("5b0217001b5a55208150cc9b"), title: 'Hi', body: 'Whoa!', __v: 0 })
Mongoose: users.update({ _id: ObjectId("5b0217001b5a55208150cc9b") }, { '$push': { posts: ObjectId("5b0217001b5a55208150cc9c") } }, {})
```

Showing that the update fires with the correct detail.

In good design you really should avoid this and simply drop the `posts` array from the `User` model. You can always either use a [virtual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) instead:

```
userSchema.virtual('posts', {
  ref: 'Post',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'user'
})
```

Or just get the data via [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/):

```
User.aggregate([
   { "$match": { "_id": userId } }
   { "$lookup": {
     "from": Post.collection.name,
     "localField": "_id",
     "foreignField": "user",
     "as": "posts"
   }}
])
```

Storing and maintaining arrays of related `ObjectId` values "on the parent" is kind of an "anti-pattern" and leads to unnecessary overhead such as writing in two places where you only need "one".

Also in general you should be opting for embedding "first", and only considering "referencing" if and when the usage pattern of the application actually demands it. Simply copying the same patterns of an RDBMS with a database engine that was not designed for that is not the best way to utilize it.

Comment: I tip my fez to you sir! I really must have been out of it.